# How can I collapse all tabs in a vertical accordion with Javascript

Tags: javascript, accordion

I made the following accordion, as indicated by w3school.

It works correctly, but want to collapse all panels by clicking on the same parent tab and/or outside the accordion elements (i.e. everywhere in the DOM except in elements `.tab` and `.tabcontent`) ?

**UPDATE (SEE SNIPPET)**
I found how to close the menu when clicking outside of it.

Still I need to close (toggle?) the panel when clicking ALSO on its parent tab (e.g. open "London" and close it either if I click on "Paris" and "London" as well)

```js
//function to open accordion
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

//function to open sidebar

function openSidebar(x) {
  document.getElementById("sidenav").classList.toggle("sidenav-visible");
  x.classList.toggle("change");

  //closes all the tabs
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (itab = 0; itab < tabcontent.length; itab++) {
    tabcontent[itab].style.display = "none";
  }
}

//closes the menu when clicking outside 

window.addEventListener('click', function(e){
if (!document.getElementById('sidenav').contains(e.target) && (!document.getElementById('burger').contains(e.target))){
 document.getElementById('sidenav').classList.remove("sidenav-visible"); 
  document.getElementById('burger').classList.remove("change");
  } 
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
}

/*Togge burger button to open sidebar menu*/
  .container-burger {
    position:absolute;
    top:0.5em;
    left: 0.5em;
    z-index:450;
  }
  .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  
  .change .bar1 {
    transform: translate(0, 11px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  
  .change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}
  
  .change .bar3 {
    transform: translate(0, -11px) rotate(45deg);
  }
.sidenav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    top:70px;
    background-color: #feffff00;
    z-index:40;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;

  }

  .sidenav-visible {
    width: 60%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 60px;
  height: 300px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  display: block;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: black;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  float: left;
  background-color:#fff;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  border-left: none;
  height: 300px;
  display:none;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">
  <!--burger button to open sidebar menu-->
    <div id="burger" class="container-burger" onclick="openSidebar(this)" title="Filters and Info">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div><!--ends burger button-->
  
    <div class="sidenav" id="sidenav">
      <!--starts the accordion-->
        <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
        </div>

        <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
          <h3>London</h3>
          <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
          <h3>Paris</h3>
          <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
        </div>

        <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
          <h3>Tokyo</h3>
          <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It already collapses when the "X" is clicked. So is your question just about closing the menu when user clicks outside of it?

Comment: @zer00ne yes exactly. The other question is: how to close the panel when I click back its parent tab, not only when I open a second tab.

Comment: IC, you'd like to know how to toggle the tabs, OK, it'll be a minute.

Comment: @zer00ne just found the way to close the menu when clicking outside of it (see snippet) but I don't know how to close the panel when clicking on its parent tab

Comment: @zer00ne have you seen my last comment? Do you have any suggestion about it? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I was on the road for the last couple of days, see [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74215128/2813224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example features a sidebar nav that will reveal a hidden menu when the "hamburger" button is clicked. The hamburger button is a toggle which means it has two states (show sidebar/hide sidebar). I added the "off-click" function from OP and of course added a function that makes the buttons (`button.link`) that open the sub-menus (`section.content.visible`) into toggles.

This answer will address the problem addressed in the question, wherein the `button.link`s need to be toggles.

```
  // Collect all button.link into a NodeList and convert it into an array
  const links = [...document.querySelectorAll(".link")];
  // Collect all section.content into a NodeList and convert it into an array as well
  const content = [...document.querySelectorAll(".content")];
  
  /**
   * For each button.link bind it to the "click" event. When triggered, 
   * the event handler openSub(e) will be invoked.
   */
  links.forEach(btn => btn.onclick = openSub);
```

By default, event handlers always passes the Event Object (evt)
Reference the element that has an #id identical to "this" [name]
"this" refers to the element that's bound to the "click" event.
Next, iterate through the links array.
If the current `button.link` is the `button.link` that is registered to this "click" event, toggle the `.visible` class on the `section.content` associated with the current `button.link` then toggle the `.active` class on the current `button.link` Otherwise, remove the `.visible` class from the current `section.content` and the .active class from `button.link`.

```
function openSub(evt) {
  let synced = document.getElementById(this.name);
  links.forEach((btn, idx) => {
    if (btn === evt.currentTarget) {
      synced.classList.toggle("visible");
      btn.classList.toggle("active");
    } else {
      content[idx].classList.remove("visible");
      btn.classList.remove("active");
    }
  });
}
```

Since the majority of the elements are either absolutely or relatively positioned, all `section.content` are absolutely positioned and have an offset of -15vw which translate as:

Position element to the left side of relatively positioned parent element. The negative value will end up outside of parent 15% of viewport from the element's original position. The initial width and opacity of element will be 0 (making it virtually non-existent). When `section.content` is assigned a `.visible` class, it's width extends to 15vw, it's opacity increases to max (1.0). It's then moved from left to right for 30% of viewport.

**Note**: the transition values are set so that upon `section.content.visible` being returned on an animation of `translateX()` is cut abruptly (`transition: 0s`). Contrary to the previous objective, the transition is 0.8s which will show the animation within a longer timeframe.

```
 .content {
    position: absolute;
    left: -15vw;
    width: 0;
    /*...*/   
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0s;
  }
  .content.visible {
    width: 15vw;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(30vw);
    transition: 0.8s;
  }
```

**Note:** the example is not responsive so the code rendered in the answer within the iframe is distorted. Review this answer in full page mode.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
  *,
  *::before,
  *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  :root {
    --shadow_out: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15),
      0px 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0px 16px 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    --shadow_btn: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15),
      0px 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0px 16px 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  }

  html {
    font: 300 2ch/1 "Segoe UI";
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }

  main {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-color: grey;
  }

  .burger {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5em;
    left: 0.5em;
    z-index: 45;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .bar {
    display: block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    margin: 6px 0;
    background: #fff;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }

  .change .b1 {
    transform: translate(0, 11px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  .change .b2 {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .change .b3 {
    transform: translate(0, -11px) rotate(45deg);
  }

  .slide {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: -30vw;
    z-index: 46;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  .tab {
    width: 15vw;
    min-height: 300px;
  }

  .tab button {
    display: block;
    padding: 1.25rem 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: left;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: var(--shadow_out);
  }

  .tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }

  .tab button:active,
  .tab button.active {
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: #ccc;
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  .content {
    position: absolute;
    left: -15vw;
    width: 0;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 0px 0.65rem;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: none;
    background: #def;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0s;
    box-shadow: var(--shadow_btn);
  }

  .slide.visible {
    width: 30vw;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(30vw);
  }

  .content.visible {
    width: 15vw;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(30vw);
    transition: 0.8s;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <menu class="burger" title="Capital">
      <b class="bar b1"></b>
      <b class="bar b2"></b>
      <b class="bar b3"></b>
    </menu>
    <nav class="slide">
      <menu class="tab">
        <button name="London" class="link">London</button>
        <button name="Paris" class="link">Paris</button>
        <button name="Tokyo" class="link">Tokyo</button>
      </menu>
      <section id="London" class="content">
        <h3>England</h3>
        <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
      </section>
      <section id="Paris" class="content">
        <h3>France</h3>
        <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
      </section>
      <section id="Tokyo" class="content">
        <h3>Japan</h3>
        <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
      </section>
    </nav>
  </main>
  <script>
  
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const slide = document.querySelector('.slide');
  
  const links = [...document.querySelectorAll(".link")];
  const content = [...document.querySelectorAll(".content")];
  
  burger.onclick = openNav;
  window.onclick = exitNav;
  links.forEach(btn => btn.onclick = openSub);

  function openNav(evt) {
    content.forEach(sec => sec.classList.remove("visible"));
    slide.classList.toggle("visible");
    this.classList.toggle("change");
  }

  function exitNav(evt) {
    if (!slide.contains(evt.target) && !burger.contains(evt.target)) {
      slide.classList.remove("visible");
      burger.classList.remove("change");
    }
  }
  
  function openSub(evt) {
    let synced = document.getElementById(this.name);
    links.forEach((btn, idx) => {
      if (btn === evt.currentTarget) {
        synced.classList.toggle("visible");
        btn.classList.toggle("active");
      } else {
        content[idx].classList.remove("visible");
        btn.classList.remove("active");
      }
    });
  }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```